# How can i run a loop that adds values to a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

my files names look like this:

```
data00001
data00002
data00003
....
data00010
....
```

i have them saved and want to download them from the website they're in using this code:

```
import urllib.request as urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen("https://somewebsite/data00001.mat")
file = open(r"C:\Users\me\Desktop\data\data00001.mat", 'wb')
file.write(response.read())
file.close()
```

i shall give the starting and end file name for example:

from data00001 to data01000 so in this example i want the files from data0001 to data01000 downloaded.
how can i increment the numeric value near data to make that work?

Comment: On the third question, I tell you - that's done with loops, and you don't show an intent of using one (not knowing the backstory of copying others answers and putting them as your questions). And here we are, asking how to do a loop in a programmic language - point 0 of pretty much any starting tutorial. Please, do stop it. Spend an hour learning the basics, try to solve it yourself - you will spare your own, and everyone else's time.

Comment: The worst part in this question is that it answeres itself: run a loop that adds to a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
for i in range(1, 1001):
    filename = "data" + str(i).zfill(4) + ".mat" # gives a padding of four digits
```

You can use filename for all your operations

Comment: Kudos for the usage of `zfill()`, it's in the stdlib and does precisely the needed op; you forgot to put the file suffix at the end (the ".mat" extension) ;).

Answer (score 0):

You can use integer range and formatted print with zero padding:

```
import urllib.request as urllib2

for i in range(1000):
    filename = 'data{:05d}.mat'.format(i)
    response = urllib2.urlopen("https://somewebsite/" + filename)
    file = open(r"C:\Users\me\Desktop\data\" + filename, 'wb')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly easy to retrieve all your files within a loop:

```
import urllib.request as urllib2

counter = 1
limit = 1000
filename = "data"

for i in range(limit+1):
    newFilename = "".join([filename,str(i).zfill(5)])
    response = urllib2.urlopen("https://somewebsite/" + newFilename + ".mat")
    file = open(r"C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\data\\" + newFilename + ".mat", 'wb')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()
```